# Recommended IDE for developing Pylons apps

Tags: python, ide, pylons

I have been reading through this wonderful website regarding the recommended Python IDEs and have narrowed it down to either

1. WingIDE
2. KomodoIDE

which you guys will recommend for the purpose of developing Pylons apps? I know that most questions have been asked pertaining to Python IDEs but how about Python web framework IDEs which is a mishmash of various templating languages and Python itself.

One con i have to raise about WingIDE on Windows is that it has an AWFUL interface (probably cos of the GTK+ toolkit?)

I have been using e-text editor all the while and increasingly been dissatisfied with it especially when its unable to do correct syntax highlighting at times. Furthermore I am hoping syntax coloration can be done for Mako templates.

Thank you very much all and have a great day!

Comment: I can't believe this question keeps popping up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784/poll-which-python-ide-editor-is-the-best http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows

Comment: hi this topic is Pylons-only, not a generic Python IDE question. Pylons is a web appication framework and therefore development of Pylons projects is very different from conventional Python dev. :)

Comment: Honestly it does not matter that much that it is pylons. And developing pylons project is not all that different. The only thing that is specific to pylons is the paste commands, which you have to write form the command line anyway. Also to debug pylons you just have to set paste as the main script of the project (as with Wing you cannot specify --reload parameter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after very very careful comparison, KomodoIDE 5.1 is most suitable for my purposes.

Reasons:

1. Extensibility
2. Support for Mako and YUI (required by me)
3. Native interface support (no GTK unfamiliarity)
4. Support for Mercurial SCM (required by me)

thats all I guess. I am extremely satisfied with KomodoIDE and have just shelled out some money to buy it.

I figured when making a choice of tools, spend a day or two (yes, it takes time) trying them out and choosing what best suits your day-to-day purposes. If its just your first time coding, using a standard free tool or open source tool is far more useful than expending the time to find out the best tool.

Only after some degree of expertise is acquired, you have a very narrow spectrum of requirements/preferences which will make choosing a tool far easier.

Answer (score 13):

Did you try [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) plugin? Which is FREE plus works for any OS.

Screenshots [at the PyDev website](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html).

[image: Code completion screenshot]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/images/screenshot/screenshot2.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 for Eclipse.  I use it for Turbogears 2 which is Based on Pylons.

Comment: Eclipse+pydev is good for development of almost any kind of python app. I've used for all sorts of projects - django/pylons/turbogears included.

Comment: Plus eclipse and PyDev are free. WingIDE - free 30-day trial and KomodoIDE also some trial period.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for WingIDE, It supports [debugging pylons app](http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/paste-pylons).

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) has implemented [beta](http://www.netbeans.org/features/python/index.html) support of python development. It unfortunately doesn't specifically support any templating languages that I know of, but I've been satisfied so far with its syntax highlighting and auto-complete (especially from imported modules).

Since everyone has a different preference for their coding environment, I suggest you just try out every IDE/editor you can get your hands on; so you can find the best mix-match of features that you're specifically looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Stani's Python Editor](http://pythonide.blogspot.com/) for most Python-esque editing tasks on Windows & Linux.  I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) for editing HTML, XML, CSV, and other text based "code like" files on Windows.  They are both free, and meet my needs for home based weekend projects.

I have used [Wing IDE 101](http://www.wingware.com/wingide-101), but I never the full versions.  I did not do enough with WingIDE to develop any muscle memory, so it still feels a little artificial to me.  YMMV.

To a certain degree, the IDE will influence how you think about the process of creating and debugging code.  So you should take some time to try a few different options and see which makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Aptana Studio... It's eclipse+pydev+web stuff, it doesnt have any specific pylons stuff or mako support. But eclipse+pydev alone is great + all the nice jscript+html+css stuff aptana adds.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Spyder. Never heard of it before reading this page. Working great so far.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've also been looking for a good Pylons web app IDE.  Seems like KomodoIDE 5.1 kicks some serious ass.  I love the support for Mako and that it supports pretty much all of the SCMs.

I've been using Textmate, but KomodoIDE will take over from now onwards

Answer (score 0):

I'v been using Spyderlib for some time, its really worth trying.

http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/

http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/4f41aef28be741e5